# How to write an eclipse content assist?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2, content-assist

I want to write a plugin which will give me content assist support and work in JSF. I want it to work like the sample below :

- I'll type "p:button action="#{
- Then I'll press "Ctrl+Shift+Space" (for example)
- It'll read the classes in my project and show them as a list in a pop-up window
- Then I'll select one class. It'll be like below
- h:button action="#{MyClass
- When I type "." , It'll read the methods in my selected class and show them as a list in a pop-up window.
- Then I'll select a method
- Finally, It'll end like this "h:button action="#{MyClass.MyMethod}

Do you have any idea, how can i do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

One place to look for an example of content assist is to look at [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) which already has this feature for DSL-like languages.

[image: XText content assist]

See the XText sources in [its Git repository](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/tree/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext): by [looking work the log message 'assist'](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/search?l=java&p=1&q=assist&utf8=%E2%9C%93), you will have a list of commits all related to content assist implementation, like the [`XbaseProposalProvider.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.ui/src/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/ui/contentassist/XbaseProposalProvider.java) class.

Answer (score 1):

The following are both screenshots from the [Web Page Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsf/docs/tutorial/JSFTools_1_0_tutorial.html) which comes with the Java EE edition of Eclipse.

[image: wtp editor 1]

[image]

You can install it by adding the following mirror to your Eclipse repository. Change the name depending on what version you use. For Helios it is http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I download and imported Web Page Editor.  I can write my managed beans, It supports. But not all classes, there are some classes which are not managed beans. By the way when i use  CTRL+SPace in  "action" attritube,  It just brings me managed beans , not the methods.

Comment: you can also try [JBoos Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) which has some of the features of JBoss Developer Studio. It also has a page editor (the frist one I've seen with a working preview mode  for JSF that understands templates), JBoss Tools also work good for richfaces development. Installation procedure is the same http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/ though it comes with many many tools and you should try to select only the stuff you need. I'm also looking for a JSF editor that 'just works'. But I'm too lazy to put effort in my search.